# ASP.Net MVC3 updating related models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

This is how my data model for USER looks like

```
 public class User
{
    /// <summary>
    /// .cstor
    /// </summary>
    public User()
    {
        this.UserDetails = new UserDetails();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Primary key.Identity key
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("UserDetails")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user details
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public virtual UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }        
}

public class UserDetails
{
    [Required]
    public int UserDetailsId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }        

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Create view (razor engine) where properties of User and UserDetails are filled.
But I am unable to create this because my modelstate is invalid when I save, because Userdetails.User is null. As per my understanding, this property is just to let EF know the relationship. 
Can somebody show me a neat way of doing a end to end (razor to DBcontext save) saving of these related entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a 1-to-1 relationship.

One way to do this, if it make sense in your application, is to make `UserDetails` a `ComplexType` and remove it's `User` property.

One side effect of this is that all of the data will be stored in a single table.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a Code First approach...but I should have asked first.